# mui datatable column width options is not available

Tags: mui-datatable

I am trying to set different column width for every column. But there is no option to set column width in mui datatable column options. I tried to override css properties also and that is also not working. Is there any other option to set column width .
MUIDataTableBodyCell: {
        root: {
          height: '30px',
           width: '200px'
        }
      },

Answer (score 11):

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to find a solution that worked for me.  I am using mui-datatables 3.5.0.

I was able to set the column width by setting the cell props (setCellProps). Initially, I did this for both the cell and the header, but the header did not prove to be necessary.

```
    export const columns = [
    {
        name: "category",
        label: "Category",
        options: {
            setCellProps: () => ({ style: { minWidth: "800px", maxWidth: "800px" }}),
            customBodyRender: (data, type, row) => {return <pre>{data}</pre>}
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

You would have to provide your own `columns` which is an array of objects.

```
import { myCustomColumns } from "./my_custom_columns.js";

...

<MuiDataTable ... columns={myCustomColumns} />
```

Each object on the array is a column, and that is where you will set your own `customHeadRender` on the `options` property for the object. Take a look at the code snippet below.

```
// my_custom_columns.js


/* 
   Since you are providing your own columns, the default column styling
   will be 'cleared'. The columnStyleWithWidth below will bring back the default 
   styling with the width that you would like to define.
*/

const columnStyleWithWidth = {
   top: "0px",
   left: "0px",
   zIndex: "100",
   position: "sticky",
   backgroundColor: "#fff",
   width: "300px"
}

export const columns = [
{
   name: "category",
   label: "Category",
   options: {
     ...,
     customHeadRender: ({index, ...column}) {
        return (
          <TableCell key={index} style={columnStyleWithWidth}>
              <CustomColumn label={column.label} />   
          </TableCell>
        )
     }
   }
},
...
]
```

Take note that `TableCell` is a component of `Material-UI`.