# Change column width Muidatatable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I'm trying to figure out how to change column and cells width in a Muidatable component,since there is more space than needed what triggers a horizontal scroll
here is a look at my table:

```
<MUIDataTable
          data={data}
          columns={columns(data)}
          options={{
            filterType: "textField",
            responsive: "simple",
            selectableRows: "none", // set checkbox for each row
            search: false, // set search option
            filter: false, // set data filter option
            download: false, // set download option
            print: false, // set print option
            pagination: true, //set pagination option
            viewColumns: false, // set column option
            elevation: 0,
            selectToolbarPlacement: "none",
            rowsPerPageOptions: [10, 20, 40, 80, 100],
          }}
        />
```

i would appreciate your help!

Comment: can someone help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mui datatable column width options is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303328/mui-datatable-column-width-options-is-not-available)